# UNITY C# GetComponent Returns Null

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, null

I've recently decided to look into programming in Unity using C#. I've ran into this nasty problem and I have no idea how to fix it. Pretty much when I call "instanceGo.GetComponent" it returns null. I have no idea what to do. Any ideas would help!

**CODE**

```
    // Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetKey ("p")) {
        printMessage = !printMessage;
    }
    if (instanceGo.GetComponent<SpawnZombiesHandler>() == null) {
        print ("1");
    } else {
        print ("2");
    }
    foreach(GameObject bullet in instanceGo.GetComponent<ArcherBulletShootHandler>().getBullets()){
        print ("12");
        foreach (GameObject zombie in instanceGo.GetComponent<SpawnZombiesHandler>().getZombies()) {
            hit (bullet, zombie);
            if(Mathf.RoundToInt(zombie.transform.position.y) == Mathf.RoundToInt(bullet.transform.position.y) &&
                Mathf.RoundToInt(zombie.transform.position.x) == Mathf.RoundToInt(bullet.transform.position.x)) {
                    print("HIT!");
                }
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE** It DOES print "1". Tell me if you need to see anymore code.

Thank you.

Comment: Note that `C#` and `C` are entirely different languages.

Comment: @kaylum This is C#

Comment: I know it's `C#`. But you originally had the `C` tag which someone kindly removed for you.

Comment: What line is the null reference occuring?

Comment: Could you please post a screenshot of your inspector when you have your `instanceGO` selected

Answer (score 1):

Check if the there is a component called SpawnZombiesHandler attached to instanceGo and that you have gotten capital letters in the correct places.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure instanceGo actually has attached the component you want.

Comment: When you select any object you can see in the Inspector tab all the components that it has attached. Make sure instanceGo does have the component you want (ex. SpawnZombiesHandler).